# AngularJS: Filter ng-options not having specific values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to filter on a select like so :

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-options="c as c.label group by c.type for c in columns
| filter:{c.type:'!field'} | filter:{c.type:'!map'}"></select>
```

EDIT : Adding the column model :

```
Columns = [
{
    name: "name",
    label: "Label",
    info: "Information displayed in help",
    type: "type",
    view: "html template",
    style: "min-width: 10em;",
    show: true
},
{
 ...
}
];
```

Columns is used for several things and to optimize my code I need it to be also in a Select, but without the entries whose type are 'field' nor 'map'

Yet, I get to choose from everything, even the entries which types are 'field' and 'map'.
Is there a clean way to do it ?

Comment: please post your model `columns`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

### AngularJS NOT Filter

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-options="c as c.label group by c.type for c in columns
    | filter:{ type : '!field' }
    | filter:{ type : '!map' }">
</select>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RK6P9/)**

From the **[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)**:

*"...The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with !."*

*"A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and property phone containing "1"..."*

Comment: Thanks this helped . Specifically the part about using the filter variable "type" as is . rather than c.type .