# Angular - Unable to Filter by Select with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

So I have a simple table with an ng-repeat on it. Above it I have a `<select>` with a list of countries. I want to be able to choose a country in the select and have the table only show items with that country. Pretty simple.

This is what my select looks like `<select
                        ng-model="filter.place"
                        ng-options="country.CountryName for country in countries">
                        <option value="">Select a Country</option>
                    </select>`

This is a sample of the JSON used for ng-options:

```
[
{
Id: 1
CountryName: "United Kingdom"
}
{
Id: 2
CountryName: "Afghanistan"
}
{
Id: 3
CountryName: "Albania"
}]
```

The ng-repeat is pretty standard: `<tr ng-repeat="items in events | filter:filter.place">`
Then `<td>{{items.Location.Country.CountryName}}</td>`

Whenever I choose a country from the select it returns nothing.

However I placed this tag on the page `<p>{{filter.place}}</p>` to see the contents of the model and it looks like `{"Id":7,"CountryName":"Argentina"}` So something tells me its the model has the wrong formatted data to be filtered by. How can I clean this up so it filters properly?

Comment: you might look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189406/how-to-filter-ng-options-in-angular-select

Comment: I don't see how that link answers my question. I'm trying to clean up a model not have a select have less options to choose from.

Comment: sorry, I guess I'm not sure what you're asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of `filter.place` does not match the structure of items in `events` so you can't use a pattern object as the filter. You could filter with a custom predicate:

JS

```
$scope.matchesSelectedCountryId(item) {
    return item.Location.Country.Id === $scope.filter.place.Id;
}
```

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in events | filter:matchesSelectedCountryId">
```

Or you could just filter by country name:

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in events | filter:'filter.place.CountryName'">
```

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to drll deeper into the object.