# How to render only visible items in AngularJs Dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following AngularJs object:

```
$scope.control = {'options': [{ "id": 1, "text": "Option 1", "isHidden": 0 }, { "id": 2, "text": "Option 2", "isHidden": 1 }, { "id": 3, "text": "Option 3", "isHidden": 0 }]};
```

Now, I CAN render a dropdown with all items using following:

```
<select ng-model="control.uiSelValue" ng-options="option.text for option in control.options" class="form-control"></select>
```

**How can I render only those elements which are marked "isHidden = 0"?** i.e. I want to render only "Option 1" and "Option 3" only in Dropdown.

Comment: Soltion is using the filter -  | filter:option.isHidden=0

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Filter ng-options not having specific values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189406/angularjs-filter-ng-options-not-having-specific-values)

Comment: You'll want to use `filter`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply a custom **filter** to `control.options`. You really don't need to create this filter since you can use an expression but I think it is a bad practice to make too much logic in the view.

For example:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5w3tqL8d/)

**View**

```
<select ng-model="control.uiSelValue"
        ng-options="option.text for option in control.options | filter:myFilter"
        class="form-control">
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.control = {
    options: [{
        "id": 1,
        "text": "Option 1",
        "isHidden": 0
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "Option 2",
        "isHidden": 1
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "Option 3",
        "isHidden": 0
    }]
};

$scope.myFilter = function (value) {
    return value.isHidden === 0;
};
```

Comment: +1 for not putting filter logic inside an expression. Though I'd come up with more meaningful name than `myFilter`.

Comment: I named it `myFilter` just because its an example :)

Comment: Well, I figured it out as soon as I posted. See my first comment.