# How do I filter angular results by id and other keys?

Tags: angularjs

I want to filter results by id, or rating and various other keys, I'm using this data structure:

```
[
{
    "id": "1"
    "Description": "desc 1",
    "Rating": "rating 1",
    "MainImage": "image.jpg"
},
{
    "id":"1"
    "Description": "desc 2",
    "Rating": "rating 2",
    "MainImage": "image.jpg"
},
{
    "id": "2"
    "Description": "desc 3",
    "Rating": "rating 3",
    "MainImage": "image.jpg"
}
]
```

This data is returned from a promise and is assigned to `$scope.results`.  In the template there is an `ng-repeat` to iterate over the results.  This is working fine, my question is:

How do I filter the results by `id` so for example only the results with the `id` of 1 are displayed?  I had this working but it wasn't the most efficient.  I reassigned the filtered results back to `$scope.results` which did work but then the entire data structure had been replaced by the one containing the filtered results.  That obviously wasn't going to work and I did a work around but I know this isn't the best way.

I need a custom filter that will be able to handle filtering using 3 different select lists so for example a `rating` select list, a `productId` and a `productName`.

How exactly would I write this function?

```
<div class="product" data-ng-repeat="product in products | filter:searchFilter"></div>
```

Comment: Off topic: ID values should be unique, regardless of their application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter by object property in angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793751/how-to-filter-by-object-property-in-angularjs)

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874748/how-to-render-only-visible-items-in-angularjs-dropdown/26874894#26874894](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874748/how-to-render-only-visible-items-in-angularjs-dropdown/26874894#26874894)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721863/angularjs-how-to-get-an-ngrepeat-filtered-result-reference) and created a function in the backend.  Something like:

```
$scope.searchFilter = function (item) {
    return (item.id === $scope.results.id)
}
```

This code isn't exactly what I've used but that's the general idea.  Seems to work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//This will filter the product list based on all 3 criteria
<div class="product" data-ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{rating:selectedRating, id:selectedId,productName:selectedProduct }"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it.

```
<input type="number" ng-modal="idFilter:selectedID">
<div ng-repeat="result in results | idFilter:selectedID | track by $index">
<something-repeated>
</div>

<script>
 angular.module('whatever').filter('idFilter', function(){
  return function(results, selectedID){
    return results.filter(function(result){
      return result.id == selectedID;
    });
  }
});
</script>
```