# AngularJS: ng-options add only one each of possible field values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have an array like the one in the AngularJS ngOptions documentation

```
[
  {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
  {name:'white', shade:'light', notAnOption: true},
  {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
  {name:'blue', shade:'dark', notAnOption: true},
  {name:'yellow', shade:'light', notAnOption: false}
];
```

using...

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name group by color.shade for color in colors">
```

produces...

```
dark  
  black  
  red  
  blue
light  
  white
  yellow
```

I would like to filter values by dark and light, so I would like just...

```
dark  
light
```

Is it possible using ng-options to accomplish this?

Comment: looks like you can use a filter in your `ng-options` attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189406/angularjs-filter-ng-options-not-having-specific-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use filter like this

```
 <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.shade for color in Colors | unique:'shade'"></select>
```

add AngularJS filter with 'unique'

```
app.filter('unique', function () {
return function (input, key) {
    var unique = {};
    var uniqueList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined") {
            unique[input[i][key]] = "";
            uniqueList.push(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return uniqueList;
   };
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a custom filter like Alex says, or might be able to get away with a default filter like this (if you only want to show dark or light colours in the `select`):

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name group by color.shade for color in colors | { color: { shade: shadeModel }}">
```

Where `shadeModel` could be ' ', 'dark' or 'light'