# How to fill dropdown by matching key from array inside ng repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I am having json structure like this:

```
101 :
     "List": [
      {
        "Name": "Pink"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Black"
      }
    ]

102 :
     "List": [
      {
        "Name": "Red"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Yellow"
      }
    ]

$scope.Ids = [101,102,103,104];
```

Now i have 1 ng repeat loop looping on the List of Ids (For eg:101,102) and so i want to fill dropdown by specific Id.For eg for Id 101 i would like to fill Pink,Black and for 102 i would like to fill Red,Yellow in my dropdown and for rest i would like to simply ignore but i am not getting how to achieve this.

**code:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Ids track by item.id">
  <select ng-model="color" ng-options="">
         <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: try `ng-options="{item.List}"`

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki :Thanks but can you please post whole ng-options??

Comment: You can use ng-filter, here is an example that can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189406/angularjs-filter-ng-options-not-having-specific-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the dropdown map is stored in an object: `$scope.map`:

```
<div ng-repeat="id in Ids">
  <select ng-model="color" ng-options="opt.name for opt in map[id].list"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="level1 in Ids">
  <select ng-model="color" ng-options="level2 for level2 in level1.List">  
   </select>
</div>
```

you don't need `option` tag!